# KBX extension calling ruleset twice

Tags: krl

I recently found a bug in [TomatoFlix](https://apps.kynetx.com/installable_apps/3459-TomatoFlix) through the KBX. When the user is logged in on Netflix (different from the non-logged-in interface), the rating banner gets added twice:

[image: Doubled rating banner]

I added some emits to my rules to show when the rule is getting fired. The code now looks like this:

```
rule netflix_loggedin {
    select when pageview "movies.netflix.com/.*?Movie/(.*)/" setting (movieTitle)
    pre {
      title = movieTitle.replace(re/[-_]/g, " ");
      div = getRatings(title, "", "lycoflix");
    }
    emit <|
        console.log("TomatoFlix fired!");
    |>;
    before("p.synopsis", div);
    }

rule netflix_two {
    select when pageview "movies.netflix.com/.*?Movie/(.*)/" setting (movieTitle)
    emit <|
        console.log("TomatoFlix second rule fired!");
    |>;
}
```

The JavaScript console shows the following four lines:

```
TomatoFlix fired!
TomatoFlix second rule fired!
TomatoFlix fired!
TomatoFlix second rule fired!
```

This doesn't happen with a bookmarklet or with the standalone browser extension. Only in the KBX.

The `dispatch` block has two domains in it: `www.netflix.com` and `movies.netflix.com`

Ideas?

Comment: Which KBX? Firefox4, Firefox, Chrome, or all of them?

Comment: Chrome. Haven't tested any others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I have experienced double rule firing when using a combination of browser extensions, site tags and/or proxy servers for deployment of Rulesets, I have not experienced double rule firing with just the KBX. To help isolate the issue have you disabled all other KBX applications and all other Kynetx based browser extensions?

In the meantime a work around would be to place guard rule in application. This guard rule would check for the existence of a tag within the DOM, and it it does not exist then continue running. Otherwise stop. Here's a sample:

```
rule CodeMonkey_Hack {
  select when pageview ".*"
    pre {
      tagMonkey = "<div id='CodeMonkey' style='display:none;'>CodeMonkey</div>";
      CodeMonkey = 0;
    }
    {
      emit <|
        CodeMonkey = $KOBJ("#CodeMonkey").length;
        if (!CodeMonkey) {
          $KOBJ("body").append(tagMonkey);
          app = KOBJ.get_application("a169x274");
          app.raise_event("impactblog_init", {});
        }
      |>;
    }
    always {
      last
    }
}
```

Comment: I've got some CSS that just hides the extra ones, which fixes it. Although oddly the double firing seems to have stopped now...